# Script select change runs only once

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file that hides/shows fields upon selecting an option from the selector. But when i go to a different option and i try to go back to the previous one the changes aren't happening. The html selector values are the one you see in the if statements. Removed some of the variables so i can post the code here.

JS

```
function change(obj) {
    var selectBox = obj;
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var num_floor = document.getElementById("num_floor");
    var sq_floor = document.getElementById("sq_floor");
    var podrum = document.getElementById("podrum");
    var br_balkon = document.getElementById("br_balkon");
    var lift = document.getElementById("lift");
    var sprat = document.getElementById("sprat");
    var ori = document.getElementById("ori");
    var year_built = document.getElementById("year_built");
    var parking = document.getElementById("parking");
    var num_rooms = document.getElementById("num_rooms");
    var num_toilets = document.getElementById("num_toilets");


    if(selected == 'Куќа') {
        lift.style.display = "none";
        iyear_built.required = true;
        iparking.required = true;
        isqmeter.required = true;
        inum_rooms.required = true;
        inum_toilets.required = true;
        inum_floor.required = true;
        isq_floor.required = true;
        ipodrum.required = true;
        ibr_balkon.required = true;
        isprat.required = true;
        iori.required = true;
    } else if(selected == 'Стан') {
        sq_floor.style.display = "none";
        num_floor.style.display = "none";
        ilift.required = true;
        iyear_built.required = true;
        iparking.required = true;
        isqmeter.required = true;
        inum_rooms.required = true;
        inum_toilets.required = true;
        ipodrum.required = true;
        ibr_balkon.required = true;
        isprat.required = true;
        iori.required = true;
    } else if(selected == 'Соба') {
        num_floor.style.display = "none";
        ori.style.display = "none";
        sq_floor.style.display = "none";
        br_balkon.style.display = "none";
        podrum.style.display = "none";
        lift.style.display = "none";
        num_rooms.style.display = "none";
        num_toilets.style.display = "none";
        parking.style.display = "none";
        year_built.style.display = "none";
        sprat.style.display = "none";
    } else if(selected == 'Викендица') {
        lift.style.display = "none";
        sprat.style.display = "none";
        iyear_built.required = true;
        iparking.required = true;
        isqmeter.required = true;
        inum_rooms.required = true;
        inum_toilets.required = true;
        inum_floor.required = true;
        isq_floor.required = true;
        ipodrum.required = true;
        ibr_balkon.required = true;
        iori.required = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: How are you catching the change (event)? Or, what triggers your `change()` function to fire?

Comment: how is this function called?

Comment: @ItoPizarro when i select an option in HTML it changes the input fields that need to be filled out.

Comment: @atmd the function is called `change`

Comment: @binary0011 "how" is it called, not "what" is it called. where is the code that calls it?

Comment: @atmd  `<select id = "show" name = "type" onchange = "change(this)">
                        <option name = "barrack2" value = "Барака">Барака</option>
                    </select>`

Comment: @binary0011 That is how a select element works, yes. But do you have a mechanism — often an event listener (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) — set to re-trigger your `change()` function on subsequent interactions?

Comment: @binary0011 Maybe try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)